# How exactly a file is uploaded via multipart/form-data.. using which format - UTF8, Base64, or anything else

Tags: file-upload, salesforce, alfresco, apex-code, multipartform-data

UTF8, base64 Formats

Hi All,

Here is my question.. I would like to understand how or in which format the file contents are transmitted to server when uploaded through multipart/form-data..

As I am trying to upload file along with few params to a server[Alfresco] from my code[Salesforce - Apex] and server seems to recognize none from my request. Meanwhile When I try to upload using any REST Client tester, I works fine and the document is uploaded in the server.

I managed to put a sniffer at the Server end and traced the incoming http packets from both Salesforce-Apex code and REST Client Tester. Both seem to be same and still Server responds 200 OK for REST Client and 400 Bad Request for my code.

Below is the sample trace fetched from my sniffer shown in String. I would like to know how exactly is the below HTTP Request's Body i.e., multipart/form-data beginning with the boundary string is traversing in wire.

Is it in **String, Blob, UTF-8, Base64 Encoded** or **any other format**

Can anyone provide me a depth knowledge on the same. And also about these formats as I find it hard to understand what exactly is this formats and how are these formed and decrypted.

```
POST /alfresco/service/api/upload?alf_ticket=TICKET_f1fbae39901a12ce8e33a75b84b5931661f0acbb HTTP/1.0
SFDC_STACK_DEPTH: 1
User-Agent: SFDC-Callout/31.0
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarynwLnClZSXCKQvu3H
Pragma: no-cache
Host: myAlfrescoServer:8080
Content-Length: 581
Via: 1.1 proxy-was.net.salesforce.com:8080 (squid)
X-Forwarded-For: 10.236.12.23
Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=259200
Connection: keep-alive

------WebKitFormBoundarynwLnClZSXCKQvu3H
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"

12.txt
------WebKitFormBoundarynwLnClZSXCKQvu3H
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"

PPPPPPPPP
------WebKitFormBoundarynwLnClZSXCKQvu3H
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="siteid"

edms
------WebKitFormBoundarynwLnClZSXCKQvu3H
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="containerid"

documentLibrary
------WebKitFormBoundarynwLnClZSXCKQvu3H
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filedata"; filename="12.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

123
------WebKitFormBoundarynwLnClZSXCKQvu3H--
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to decode form data on the server side you really ought to be looking at using the relevant helpers in your language of choice. In PHP that is `$_POST`, in Java something like `FileItem` for files, or Perl's `CGI->param` etc.

In particular, Alfresco's WebscriptServletRequest helper should take most of the pain out and by the sounds of it this is working fine for you. Why don't you send a REST request through your sniffer too and compare it with the Salesforce one? And what kind of errors are you getting on your Alfresco?

For your information however, `multipart/form-data` is complicated but the short of it is that it uses [7-bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa579621(v=exchg.140).aspx).

Further reading is here:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2
- http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2048.txt
- http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt

You may find the relevant part in section six of RFC2045:

```
6.1.  Content-Transfer-Encoding Syntax

The Content-Transfer-Encoding field's value is a single token
specifying the type of encoding, as enumerated below.  Formally:

 encoding := "Content-Transfer-Encoding" ":" mechanism

 mechanism := "7bit" / "8bit" / "binary" /
              "quoted-printable" / "base64" /
              ietf-token / x-token

These values are not case sensitive -- Base64 and BASE64 and bAsE64
are all equivalent.  An encoding type of 7BIT requires that the body
is already in a 7bit mail-ready representation.  This is the default
value -- that is, "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7BIT" is assumed if the
Content-Transfer-Encoding header field is not present.
```